# google compute engine mean deployment failed

Tags: google-compute-engine, mean-stack

My Google Compute Engine click-to-deploy mean stack deployment failed with the error:

"Replica mean-m9df failed with status PERMANENTLY_FAILING: Replica State changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2 consecutive times"

Following the instructions on the troubleshooting page I tailed the stdout file and saw this line:

```
Running command: curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost:3000
```

showed the followed this error:

```
000Command 'curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost:3000' failed -  retry after sleep 2 seconds...
```

repeated ~ 50 times.

How do I fix this error?

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=204  , you can star on this public issue tracker to get update notifications for the fix.

Comment: As an alternative, you can also launch [MEAN on GCP via Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/mean/cloud/google).

Answer (score 1):

We just pushed a fix to production to fix this issue.  MEAN now deploys normally.  Thanks for raising this issue and sorry for the inconvenience.

Chris

Comment: Phil, if you still see the error, run the following command once to delete the old MEAN template and deploy it again:       $ gcloud preview deployment-manager templates delete mean